# Could not find a value associated with JSONKey in SecretString

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I want to make `RDS` and `proxy` with credential

However, I bumped into this error.

```
14:32:32 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::RDS::DBCluster                         | DatabaseB269D8BB
Could not find a value associated with JSONKey in SecretString
```

My script is like this below.

```
const rdsCredentials: rds.Credentials =  rds.Credentials.fromGeneratedSecret(dbInfos['user'],{secretName:`cdk-st-${targetEnv}-db-secret`});
const dbCluster = new rds.DatabaseCluster(this, 'Database', {
  parameterGroup,
  engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraMysql({ version: rds.AuroraMysqlEngineVersion.VER_2_08_1 }),
  credentials: rdsCredentials,
  cloudwatchLogsExports:['slowquery','general','error','audit'],
  backup: backupProps,
  instances:2,
  removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  clusterIdentifier: dbInfos['cluster'], //clusterIdentifier,
  defaultDatabaseName :dbInfos['database'], //defaultDatabaseName,
  instanceProps: {
    // optional , defaults to t3.medium
    instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, ec2.InstanceSize.SMALL),
    vpcSubnets: {
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
    },
    vpc,
    securityGroups:[dbSecurityGroup],
  },
});

const proxy = new rds.DatabaseProxy(this, 'Proxy', {
  proxyTarget: rds.ProxyTarget.fromCluster(dbCluster),
  secrets: [dbCluster.secret!],
  vpc,
});
```

I guess this error is related to secrets: `[dbCluster.secret!]` maybe.

I googled around and found this error happens when secrets are deleted.

However I want to use credential which is just generated for `RDS`

Is it impossible?

how can I fix this?

**More Test**

I tried another way but this comes the error below

```
/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-rds/lib/proxy.ts:239
      secret.grantRead(role);
```

my code is here

```
dbCluster.addProxy('testProxy',{
  secrets: [rdsCredentials.secret!],
        vpc
});
```

Comment: I have not worked on CDK, but what we can do is, we can test if we are able to generate the secret successfully and use it. You can use the following command to generate and use the credentials. `credentials: rds.Credentials.fromGeneratedSecret('postgres'), // Creates an admin user of postgres with a generated password`

Comment: Thank you for your hint I found out, that `dbInfos['user']` doesn't return the data. so  `fromGeneratedSecret` does not make secret properly